# How can I make Flash Builder 4 launch browser on run?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder

I recently installed Adobe Flash Builder 4 in standalone mode on a new installation of Windows 7 x64.

I can load and build an existing Flex 4.1 project I have been working on, but when I go to run the project in the browser (Firefox 3.6.15), I get:

> 'Launching BensApp' has encountered a problem.
>
> An internal error occurred during: 'Launching BensApp'

Clicking the *Details >>* button reveals:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

My project is creating the SWF and container HTML page as expected, but fails to load the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Finally nutted this out.

The problem was that Flash Builder was trying to run the ASP.NET web server at:

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Shared\9.0\WebDevServer.exe

This is the default location if you have VS2008 installed.

I only have VS2010 installed, which places these files at ...\Shared\10.0.  The solution was to copy WebDevServer20.exe to the above location.

The other solution that would work is to change Flex Server \ Application Server type to "None\Other".

Answer (score 0):

Check the launch configurations located in Project>Properties>Run/Debug Settings.

To open a browser when you run the project you will need to modify the 'URL or path to launch' parameter.

See the Adobe Flex help for more info: [Managing Launch Configurations](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compile_debug_4.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The documentation was interesting to read, but it doesn't resolve the problem I am having, which seems to be a broken launch process.

Comment: Does flash builder throw any errors when you build the project?

Answer (score 0):

Select "Run As" in Green Debug Button. It Fixed My Problem.